# Ebay Api: list of items with date filter in coldfusion

Tags: xml, coldfusion, ebay-api

I need to update my database with some data retrieved from the ebay api with the itemId key.
I work with coldfusion so I need to comunicate with the api and send an input xml and retrieve the response.

The method I use to retrieve this data is GetMyeBaySellingRequest:
http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/getmyebayselling.html

Api test tool:
https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/build-test/test-tool/default.aspx

Xml:

```
    <?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
    <GetMyeBaySellingRequest xmlns=""urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents"">
#ebayCredentials#
    <DetailLevel>ReturnSummary</DetailLevel>
    <ErrorLanguage>it_IT</ErrorLanguage>
    <Site>site</Site>
    <ActiveList>
    <IncludeNotes>false</IncludeNotes>
    <Pagination>
    <EntriesPerPage>50</EntriesPerPage>
    <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
    </Pagination>
    <ListingType>StoresFixedPrice</ListingType>
    </ActiveList>
    </GetMyeBaySellingRequest>
```

This call run e return

```
<TotalNumberOfPages>2500</TotalNumberOfPages>
<TotalNumberOfEntries>25000</TotalNumberOfEntries>
```

So I need to Filter this data with param like dateFrom and dateTo to reduce the records.
Reading the documentation ti try adding this part:

```
<DetailLevel>
<EndTimeFrom> </EndTimeFrom>
<EndTimeTo> </EndTimeTo>
</DetailLevel>
```

But I haven't a good result...
Some Suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

You are passing EndTimeFrom and EndTimeTo to wrong **DetailLevelCodeType**. That is why you are not getting desired result. You need to change the DetailLevelCodeType to **ReturnAll** instead of **ReturnSummary** and it will work.

In the second paragraph of the [first link](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/getmyebayselling.html) you provided, it is mentioned that

> If you pass a detail level that exists in the schema but that isn't
>   valid for a particular request, eBay ignores it processes the request
>   without it.

This why you are not getting error even if you are passing values (EndTimeFrom/EndTimeTo) which are not required.

I hope this helps, I gave an answer based on the link you provided. Let me know if it works. :)